# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() with CAS authentication in ASP.NET MVC deployed in IIS is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, cas

I have a VS2017 ASP.NET web application project and I'm using external CAS authentication integrated in Owin (available at https://github.com/noelbundick/Owin.Security.CAS). Running this project in Visual Studio there aren't issues and the identity is built correctly, so the ExternalLoginCallback method works fine and `loginInfo` variable is not null.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I deploy the project to an IIS server using the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio the identity is not built correctly so `loginInfo` is null and it seems that after the authentication on the external page of CAS server the deployed project is unable to call the CAS server for the service validation using the `serviceValidate` defined in CAS protocol.
In `Startup.Auth.cs` I have added the following lines:

```
CasAuthenticationOptions casOptions = new CasAuthenticationOptions
{
    CasServerUrlBase = // (here's the url of the CAS server service
};
app.UseCasAuthentication(casOptions);
```

I think it would be an issue with IIS. I would like to know if there is someone else with the same issue.